# deploying to heroku from local machine

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I have django project running on my machine in virtualenv. Is there a way I can deploy my project on Heroku directly?  I followed steps mentioned in heroku documentation but i am kind of confused with req.txt since my project already have req.txt in virtualenv. I am new to django heroku techs. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: read more blogs. You do not export your virtualenv to heroku, that is why you need to add req.txt there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my project already have req.txt in virtualenv

You should not have `req.txt` in virtualenv. You should have `requirements.txt` in your project repository. `requirements.txt` is just a list of modules that need to be installed in the virtualenv. You create and activate a new virtualenv, then you run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and it installs everything you need in the virtualenv. So `requirements.txt` is not part of the virtualenv, it's more like a description of how to setup the virtualenv.

If this is not clear, you may find my article, [virtualenv demystified](http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/), useful.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements.txt file defines what python dependencies Heroku will install. Generally speaking, what you use locally will be the same as your local development machine.

If there are differences, you may opt to have an additional file locally that contains local, development-specific packages (for example django-debug-toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

First you will activate your virtual environment and then go to project root and run the command
pip freeze > requirements.txt
This will automatically add all the dependencies of your local machine in requirements.txt. Once you push the file heroku will automatically detect the changes and install them.